# How do I get console output in C++ with a Windows program?

Tags: c++, windows, console

If I have a native C++ windows program (i.e. the entry point is WinMain) how do I view output from console functions like std::cout?

Comment: Are you trying to read your output or another applications output?

Answer (score 34):

Check out [Adding Console I/O to a Win32 GUI App](http://dslweb.nwnexus.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm). This may help you do what you want.

If you don't have, or can't modify the code, try the suggestions found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930/en-us) to redirect console output to a file.

---

**Edit:** bit of thread necromancy here. I first answered this 9ish years ago, in the early days of SO, before the (good) policy of non-link-only answers came into effect. I'll repost the code from the original article in the hope to atone for my past sins.

**guicon.cpp -- A console redirection function**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#ifndef _USE_OLD_IOSTREAMS
using namespace std;
#endif
// maximum mumber of lines the output console should have
static const WORD MAX_CONSOLE_LINES = 500;
#ifdef _DEBUG
void RedirectIOToConsole()
{
    int hConHandle;
    long lStdHandle;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO coninfo;
    FILE *fp;

    // allocate a console for this app
    AllocConsole();

    // set the screen buffer to be big enough to let us scroll text
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &coninfo);
    coninfo.dwSize.Y = MAX_CONSOLE_LINES;
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coninfo.dwSize);

    // redirect unbuffered STDOUT to the console
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "w" );
    *stdout = *fp;
    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    // redirect unbuffered STDIN to the console
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "r" );
    *stdin = *fp;
    setvbuf( stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    // redirect unbuffered STDERR to the console
    lStdHandle = (long)GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(lStdHandle, _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen( hConHandle, "w" );
    *stderr = *fp;
    setvbuf( stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    // make cout, wcout, cin, wcin, wcerr, cerr, wclog and clog
    // point to console as well
    ios::sync_with_stdio();
}

#endif
//End of File
```

**guicon.h -- Interface to console redirection function**

```
#ifndef __GUICON_H__
#define __GUICON_H__
#ifdef _DEBUG

void RedirectIOToConsole();

#endif
#endif

// End of File
```

**test.cpp -- Demonstrating console redirection**

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifndef _USE_OLD_OSTREAMS
using namespace std;
#endif
#include "guicon.h"


#include <crtdbg.h>

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    #ifdef _DEBUG
    RedirectIOToConsole();
    #endif
    int iVar;

    // test stdio
    fprintf(stdout, "Test output to stdout\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Test output to stderr\n");
    fprintf(stdout, "Enter an integer to test stdin: ");
    scanf("%d", &iVar);
    printf("You entered %d\n", iVar);

    //test iostreams
    cout << "Test output to cout" << endl;
    cerr << "Test output to cerr" << endl;
    clog << "Test output to clog" << endl;
    cout << "Enter an integer to test cin: ";
    cin >> iVar;
    cout << "You entered " << iVar << endl;
    #ifndef _USE_OLD_IOSTREAMS

    // test wide iostreams
    wcout << L"Test output to wcout" << endl;
    wcerr << L"Test output to wcerr" << endl;
    wclog << L"Test output to wclog" << endl;
    wcout << L"Enter an integer to test wcin: ";
    wcin >> iVar;
    wcout << L"You entered " << iVar << endl;
    #endif

    // test CrtDbg output
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
    _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR );
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
    _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);
    _CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE );
    _CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);
    _RPT0(_CRT_WARN, "This is testing _CRT_WARN output\n");
    _RPT0(_CRT_ERROR, "This is testing _CRT_ERROR output\n");
    _ASSERT( 0 && "testing _ASSERT" );
    _ASSERTE( 0 && "testing _ASSERTE" );
    Sleep(2000);
    return 0;
}

//End of File
```

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=509479&whichpage=1&#3320937

Comment: Good link.  The gamedev.net forums have always provided me with a wealth of information.

Comment: `*stdout = *fp` is not portable and probably doesn't even work with the Universal CRT that was introduced in 2015. Use [`freopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/freopen-wfreopen?view=vs-2019) with "CONOUT$" and "CONIN$" instead.

Comment: You may not have redeemed yourself, you may have compounded your error.  If you didn't write the code, you may not have the right to post it here unless it's available under a CC BY-SA license.

Comment: Why complicating? you just add more possible bugs.

Answer (score 26):

The problem some of the other answers is that they unnecessarily create new `FILE` instances which are then leaked and can cause debug assertions in the CRT cleanup code.

[freopen_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/freopen-s-wfreopen-s?view=vs-2019) is all that is really needed:

```
FILE* fp = nullptr;
freopen_s(&fp, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
freopen_s(&fp, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen_s(&fp, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);
```

You'll probably want to do a little error checking and cleanup as well. Below is the complete solution that I currently use.

**Redirecting Console Standard IO:**

```
bool RedirectConsoleIO()
{
    bool result = true;
    FILE* fp;

    // Redirect STDIN if the console has an input handle
    if (GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        if (freopen_s(&fp, "CONIN$", "r", stdin) != 0)
            result = false;
        else
            setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    // Redirect STDOUT if the console has an output handle
    if (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        if (freopen_s(&fp, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout) != 0)
            result = false;
        else
            setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    // Redirect STDERR if the console has an error handle
    if (GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        if (freopen_s(&fp, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr) != 0)
            result = false;
        else
            setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    // Make C++ standard streams point to console as well.
    ios::sync_with_stdio(true);

    // Clear the error state for each of the C++ standard streams.
    std::wcout.clear();
    std::cout.clear();
    std::wcerr.clear();
    std::cerr.clear();
    std::wcin.clear();
    std::cin.clear();

    return result;
}
```

**Releasing a Console:**

```
bool ReleaseConsole()
{
    bool result = true;
    FILE* fp;

    // Just to be safe, redirect standard IO to NUL before releasing.

    // Redirect STDIN to NUL
    if (freopen_s(&fp, "NUL:", "r", stdin) != 0)
        result = false;
    else
        setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    // Redirect STDOUT to NUL
    if (freopen_s(&fp, "NUL:", "w", stdout) != 0)
        result = false;
    else
        setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    // Redirect STDERR to NUL
    if (freopen_s(&fp, "NUL:", "w", stderr) != 0)
        result = false;
    else
        setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    // Detach from console
    if (!FreeConsole())
        result = false;

    return result;
}
```

**Resizing Console Buffer:**

```
void AdjustConsoleBuffer(int16_t minLength)
{
    // Set the screen buffer to be big enough to scroll some text
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO conInfo;
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &conInfo);
    if (conInfo.dwSize.Y < minLength)
        conInfo.dwSize.Y = minLength;
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), conInfo.dwSize);
}
```

**Allocating a New Console:**

```
bool CreateNewConsole(int16_t minLength)
{
    bool result = false;

    // Release any current console and redirect IO to NUL
    ReleaseConsole();

    // Attempt to create new console
    if (AllocConsole())
    {
        AdjustConsoleBuffer(minLength);
        result = RedirectConsoleIO();
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Attaching to Parent's Console:**

```
bool AttachParentConsole(int16_t minLength)
{
    bool result = false;

    // Release any current console and redirect IO to NUL
    ReleaseConsole();

    // Attempt to attach to parent process's console
    if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS))
    {
        AdjustConsoleBuffer(minLength);
        result = RedirectConsoleIO();
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Calling from WinMain:**

Link with `/SUBSYSTEM:Windows`

```
int APIENTRY WinMain(
    HINSTANCE /*hInstance*/,
    HINSTANCE /*hPrevInstance*/,
    LPTSTR    /*lpCmdLine*/,
    int       /*cmdShow*/)
{
    if (CreateNewConsole(1024))
    {
        int i;

        // test stdio
        fprintf(stdout, "Test output to stdout\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Test output to stderr\n");
        fprintf(stdout, "Enter an integer to test stdin: ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        printf("You entered %d\n", i);

        // test iostreams
        std::cout << "Test output to std::cout" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Test output to std::cerr" << std::endl;
        std::clog << "Test output to std::clog" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Enter an integer to test std::cin: ";
        std::cin >> i;
        std::cout << "You entered " << i << std::endl;

        std::cout << endl << "Press any key to continue..." << endl;
        _getch();

        ReleaseConsole();
    }

    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Can the resulting output be redirect to a file?

Answer (score 16):

You can also reopen the cout and cerr streams to output to a file as well. The following should work for this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main ()
{
    std::ofstream file;
    file.open ("cout.txt");
    std::streambuf* sbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::cout.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());
    //cout is now pointing to a file
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is an underappreciated answer. Much simpler than faffing around with `AllocConsole` etc..

Comment: Not sure I understand the point in the `std::streambuf* sbuf = std::cout.rdbuf();` line though? Doesn't appear to do anything. Will probably be optimised away most of the time anyway.

Answer (score 10):

If you are sending the output of your program to a file or pipe, e.g.

```
myprogram.exe > file.txt
myprogram.exe | anotherprogram.exe
```

or you are invoking your program from another program and capturing its output through a pipe, then you don't need to change anything. It will just work, even if the entry point is `WinMain`.

However, if you are running your program in a console or in Visual Studio, then the output will not appear in the console or in the Output window of Visual Studio. If you want to see the output "live", then try one of the other answers.

Basically, this means that standard output works just like with console applications, but it isn't connected to a console in which you are running your application, and there seems to be no easy way to do that (all the other solutions presented here connect the output to a new console window that will pop up when you run your application, even from another console).

Comment: the "attach console" solution will not pop up

Answer (score 10):

Actually there is a much simpler solution than any proposed so far. Your Windows program will have a WinMain function so just add this "dummy" main function as well

```
int main()
{
   return WinMain(GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, GetCommandLineA(), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

You can now compile using MSVC like this

```
cl /nologo /c /EHsc myprog.c
link /nologo /out:myprog.exe /subsystem:console myprog.obj user32.lib gdi32.lib
```

(you may need to add more library links)

When you run the program any `printf` will be written to the command prompt.

If you are using gcc (mingw) to compile for Windows you don't need a dummy main function, just do

```
gcc -o myprog.exe myprog.c -luser32 -lgdi32
```

(ie avoid using the `-mwindows` flag which will prevent writing to a console. That flag will be useful when you create the final GUI release) Again you may need to specify more libraries if using more windows features)

Answer (score 8):

Using a combination of [luke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/191880) and [Roger's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25927081/1513612) worked for me in my Windows Desktop Application project.

```
void RedirectIOToConsole() {

    //Create a console for this application
    AllocConsole();

    // Get STDOUT handle
    HANDLE ConsoleOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    int SystemOutput = _open_osfhandle(intptr_t(ConsoleOutput), _O_TEXT);
    FILE *COutputHandle = _fdopen(SystemOutput, "w");

    // Get STDERR handle
    HANDLE ConsoleError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    int SystemError = _open_osfhandle(intptr_t(ConsoleError), _O_TEXT);
    FILE *CErrorHandle = _fdopen(SystemError, "w");

    // Get STDIN handle
    HANDLE ConsoleInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    int SystemInput = _open_osfhandle(intptr_t(ConsoleInput), _O_TEXT);
    FILE *CInputHandle = _fdopen(SystemInput, "r");

    //make cout, wcout, cin, wcin, wcerr, cerr, wclog and clog point to console as well
    ios::sync_with_stdio(true);

    // Redirect the CRT standard input, output, and error handles to the console
    freopen_s(&CInputHandle, "CONIN$", "r", stdin);
    freopen_s(&COutputHandle, "CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    freopen_s(&CErrorHandle, "CONOUT$", "w", stderr);

    //Clear the error state for each of the C++ standard stream objects. We need to do this, as
    //attempts to access the standard streams before they refer to a valid target will cause the
    //iostream objects to enter an error state. In versions of Visual Studio after 2005, this seems
    //to always occur during startup regardless of whether anything has been read from or written to
    //the console or not.
    std::wcout.clear();
    std::cout.clear();
    std::wcerr.clear();
    std::cerr.clear();
    std::wcin.clear();
    std::cin.clear();

}
```

Comment: The block above `ios::sync_with_stdio` is not required. Moreover, it causes three `FILE` instances allocated there with `_fdopen` calls to be leaked because it's an **output** argument for `freopen_s`.

Comment: @Angstrom the docs for `freopen_s` say it "closes the file currently associated with stream and reassigns stream to the file specified by path," where _stream_ is that first arg to `freopen_s`.  So maybe @Sev is trying to close the std handles set by `AllocConsole()`?  I agree it seems misguided; might just as well use `CloseHandle()`.  Or _use_ them rather than close them and reopen them.

Answer (score 4):

creating a pipe, execute the program console CreateProcess() and read with ReadFile() or writes in console WriteFile()

```
    HANDLE hRead ; // ConsoleStdInput
    HANDLE hWrite; // ConsoleStdOutput and ConsoleStdError

    STARTUPINFO           stiConsole;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES   segConsole;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION   priConsole;

    segConsole.nLength = sizeof(segConsole);
    segConsole.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    segConsole.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

if(CreatePipe(&hRead,&hWrite,&segConsole,0) )
{

    FillMemory(&stiConsole,sizeof(stiConsole),0);
    stiConsole.cb = sizeof(stiConsole);
GetStartupInfo(&stiConsole);
stiConsole.hStdOutput = hWrite;
stiConsole.hStdError  = hWrite;
stiConsole.dwFlags    = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
stiConsole.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE; // execute hide 

    if(CreateProcess(NULL, "c:\\teste.exe",NULL,NULL,TRUE,NULL,
      NULL,NULL,&stiConsole,&priConsole) == TRUE)
    {
        //readfile and/or writefile
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Go to Project>Project Properties>Linker>System and in the right pane, set **SubSystems** option to **Console(/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)**

Then compile your program and run it from console to see whether you command prompt shows your outputs or not.

Answer (score 2):

Don't quote me on this, but the Win32 [console API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682087(VS.85).aspx) might be what you're looking for. If you're just doing this for debugging purposes, however, you might be more interested in running [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) and calling the [DbgPrint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms792790.aspx) function.

This of course assumes its your application you want sending console output, not reading it from another application. In that case, pipes might be your friend.

Comment: According to link to `DbgPrint` it holds that `Only kernel-mode drivers can call the DbgPrint routine.`. So probably not what most people wants

Comment: Huh. Well, I know there's a user-mode function for logging messages that'll appear in DebugView. I thought that DbgPrint was it, but obviously not.

Comment: The user-mode function to dump text that shows up in DebugView is [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42422951/3969362) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52717331/3969362) the easiest solution is to use your Project Property Pages to switch back and forth between `CONSOLE` and `WINDOWS` SubSytems to enable or disable console output at will.

[image: Project Properties]

Your program will just need `main` and `WinMain` entry points to make sure both configuration are compiling.
The `main` function simply calling `WinMain` as shown below for instance:

```
int main()
{
cout << "Output standard\n";
cerr << "Output error\n";

return WinMain(GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, GetCommandLineA(), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

Comment: what if i want to hide it when not in DEBUG.

Comment: I reckon that should work. Just set the SubSystem to Console only for your Debug configuration. For your Release configuration use the Windows SubSystem.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no console window, this is <strike>impossible</strike> difficult. (Learn something new every day - I never knew about the console functions!)

Is it possible for you to replace your output calls?  I will often use TRACE or OutputDebugString to send information to the Visual Studio output window.

Comment: Actually, it is possible, but tricky, to get a console window for programs using the WinMain() entry point instead of main().

Comment: @ChrisCharabaruk: It's not really tricky to call [AllocConsole](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681944.aspx). This is explained under [creation of a console](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528.aspx). Besides, the name of the user-provided entry point does not control creation of a console. It's the PE header entry for the subsystem that does (`WINDOWS` vs. `CONSOLE`). Visual Studio uses that linker setting to control, which user-provided entry point the CRT's startup code calls into.