# is it possible to redirect cout stream to a particular window(control) having the hwnd handle for it?

Tags: c++, winapi, stream, cout, richedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Redirecting cout to a console in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311955/redirecting-cout-to-a-console-in-windows)

I've created a child richedit window with `CreateWindow` and I wonder is it possible to redirect all cout calls so text would appear in RichEdit controll instead of console ?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, not the same question at all - that one is for redirecting to console, this one is for redirecting to a richedit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do that.  You need to send window messages to set the text in the control.

That's not to say you can't use stream syntax.  You could define your own `ostream` and use that instead of `cout`, then pass bytes into your window.  It wouldn't help with any output that you don't generate, nor would it help if you mix `printf` calls (which you shouldn't really do).

Comment: There are horribly ugly ways if you're desperate enough. You can intercept console I/O and redirect it to a pipe. Then you can read from the other end of the pipe and use that to update your RichEdit control.

Comment: Sheesh...  I don't think I'd be that keen, even just for an exercise! =)  Besides, I get the feeling that this is wanted as a replacement for the Console, rather than something to run alongside it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: *iteresting!* have you any code examples how to intercept console I/O. I asked for it several times and people said it is not possible.

Comment: You basically duplicate the write end of a pipe onto the descriptor that was writing to the console. Now all writes to the console will instead go to your pipe. You can then read from the other end of it. (Actually, you may need to hook your own `WriteConsoleA`.)

Comment: Feeling game enough to turn that into an answer? =)

Comment: Never mind. I found [the easy way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/424236/721269) to do it.

Comment: @paddy: yes, replacement, and my dream is to also intercept other winapi calls for the console like color and colorize richedit output. Console is really ugly it breaks lines, it has no notion of paragraphs and it is not possible to show unicode with it, and text cannot be copied alongside with color information.

Comment: @rsk82, the richedit control isn't really suited to acting like an output window because the update methods are limited. I once wrote a window class which works like Visual Studio's output window, but it was a real pain. There's lots of details I didn't anticipate before I started.

Comment: @MarkRansom: it is not suited from programmatical point of view, but is very suitable from wetware perspective. Richedit has paragraphs so you can easily see when line starts and ends if you set `PARAFORMAT` properties to space before and after paragraph. Human visual system is not well suited to monotonous stream of same sized chars like on a checkerboard.