# Console output in a window application (Visual Studio 2015, C++, SDL2)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sdl-2

I'm trying to do a few simple std::couts for debugging but because it's a window application I'm not seeing the console where the outputs would be. How do I set up visual studio so that I can see outputs to the console while running a window application?

Cheers!

Comment: This should happen already - the "Output" window should contain these. You might need to change the filter to "Debug" to see them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get console output in C++ with a Windows program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191842/how-do-i-get-console-output-in-c-with-a-windows-program)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than answer the specific question, I'll answer with one common practice mechanism for debugging Windows GUI applications which is to use the TRACE macro.  When debugging it'll end up in the Visual Studio Output window.  You can also attach other viewers.  See this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sx52ww7(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I use `OutputDebugStringA()` to output to the console window in the IDE.

You should search the MSDN site for more details.