# Where does stdout go to on windows GUI applications?

Tags: windows, stdout, win32gui

Let's say I write a windows GUI application. When started from terminal, it immediately returns and shows the GUI.

Where does stdout go to if I use something Luke `printf`in C? Is there any way to capture it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191842/how-do-i-get-console-output-in-c-with-a-windows-program)

Comment: GUI apps do not create/allocate a console by default. You can use something like OutputDebugString to write output and use DbgView to view it.