# How to set executable to Win32 in release mode

Tags: c++, cmake

I've read on CMake's documentation that when calling `add_executable`, you can set the executable type to be Win32 by doing `add_executable(target WIN32 source.cpp)`. I also know that you should use CMake generator expressions to check for build configurations like so:

```
target_compile_definitions(target PUBLIC
  $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:DEBUG>
  $<$<CONFIG:Release>:RELEASE>
)
```

However this won't work with `add_executable`. It treats it as a source file when I do `add_executable(target $<$<CONFIG:Release>:WIN32> source.cpp)` and so it fails. What is the correct way of doing setting the executable type to WIN32 only in release mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure it makes sense given a WIN32 executable and a non-WIN32 executable do not have the same entry point, so the code would need to change as well.

Still, here is how you would do it on CMake side:

```
add_executable(target source.cpp)
set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES WIN32_EXECUTABLE $<CONFIG:Release>)
```

Key point is the `WIN32` flag in [`add_executable`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) is just a shortcut to set the [`WIN32_EXECUTABLE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WIN32_EXECUTABLE.html) property.

*Note: I cannot test this sample atm so it depends on me having read those links properly ;)*

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. The reason I'm doing this is because I want to not have a console window lying around in release builds, but still keep the console for debug builds. The way I handle the entry point problem is just to use #ifdef's to check if I'm in release mode or not.

Comment: I see. That's a crude but clever solution. If you want something more fancy, you might want to check whether [How do I get console output with a windows program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191842/how-do-i-get-console-output-in-c-with-a-windows-program) could make sense for your app. Granted, your solution is much simpler, but that post might allow more control of the output. :)